# How to run HelloWorld on ARM

Tags: c++, arm, qemu

I need to run HelloWorld on arm.
I launch:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-g++ -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 -c test.cpp -o test

$ file test
test: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

$  qemu-arm test <br>
Error while loading test: Permission denied
```

Comment: I haven't used qemu much, but can you run it as an unprivileged user? You don't have to be `root` for it to work? Have you trued running with `sudo`?

Comment: No, you don't need to be root to run QEMU, and you definitely should not run it as root (running a million lines of code as root that have never been audited to be safe to run as root is not generally a good idea).

Comment: Are you really sure you want to be running a Cortex-M3 binary (microcontroller) on QEMU's user-mode ("run this Linux binary") program, rather than on full system emulation? It might work, depending on what the test program and any relevant linker script are actually doing, but on the other hand it might be totally the wrong way to run it...

Comment: it could work with the right newlib or other bare metal c library, but the machine type would most definitely need to be a cortex-m3 if nothing else to boot right.  Very highly likely what Peter is saying...your build is wrong and your qemu run is wrong.

Comment: with bare metal, a printf('Hello world\n"); is a very advanced program, if you are asking these questions you are a long way from getting something like that to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
qemu-system-arm -machine help
...
lm3s811evb           Stellaris LM3S811EVB
...
```

From either the lm3s811 datasheet or looking at the source for the stellaris backend on qemu arm hardware.  Uart0 base address is 0x4000C000, the data (rx and tx) register is offset 0x000.  From experience the qemu backends tend not to bother with the tx buffer being busy...

flash.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
    .word 0x20001000
    .word reset
    .word hang
    .word hang
    .word hang
    .word hang
    .word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang

.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr
```

uart01.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
#define UART0BASE 0x4000C000
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int rx;
    for(rx=0;rx<7;rx++)
    {
        PUT32(UART0BASE+0x00,0x30+rx);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom 
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

Yep, the stellaris was the first cortex-m3 in silicon that you could buy and I specified cortex-m0.  Basically preventing the thumb2 extensions, or most of them.  More portable, can easily change that if you want.

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn -mcpu=cortex-m0 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -c uart01.c -o uart01.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o uart01.elf -T flash.ld flash.o uart01.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D uart01.elf > uart01.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy uart01.elf uart01.bin -O binary
```

then

```
qemu-system-arm -M lm3s811evb -m 16K -nographic -kernel uart01.bin
```

and the output is

```
0123456
```

ctrl-a then press x to exit qemu.  or

```
qemu-system-arm -M lm3s811evb -m 16K -kernel uart01.bin
```

then ctrl-alt-3 (3 not F3) and the serial console pops up with the serial output.  when you close that serial console qemu closes.

I want to remember someone telling me that the qemu cortex-m3 support is not that good.

the normal arm cores should be well tested as they are used to cross compile for all kinds of arm target boards.  not sure exactly which cores are well tested, but you could do thumb stuff if you booted like an arm but did the rest in thumb, boot with

```
.globl _start
_start:
    b reset
    b hang
    b hang
    b hang
reset:
    mov sp,#0x20000
    bl notmain
hang:
    b hang
```

the machine

```
versatilepb          ARM Versatile/PB (ARM926EJ-S)
```

has its uart at 0x101f1000, so

```
for(ra=0;;ra++)
{
    ra&=7;
    PUT32(0x101f1000,0x30+ra);
}
```

can build your app with

arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mthumb -c uart01.c -o uart01.o

change your linker script to be all ram based.

```
MEMORY
{
    ram  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
   .bss  : { *(.text*) } > ram
}
```

and then

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic -kernel hello.bin
```

(hmmm, does this load at 0x0000, or 0x8000?, shouldnt be too hard to figure out)

you can get mostly the thumb feel of a cortex-m (an m0 basically not an m3, you can find an armv7-a machine you can probably run thumb2 built code (still boots like an arm not a cortex-m)).  for example

```
realview-pb-a8       ARM RealView Platform Baseboard for Cortex-A8
```

Can probably use newlib almost as is, need to change the crt0.s or whatever it is called these days to boot like an arm not a cortex-m.  The rest can build using armv7m and in theory will work.

And or start with the stellaris and just make your own hw support for whatever your real target is and fix the cortex-m3 core if/when you find problems.

Comment: Yeah, QEMU's Cortex-M3 support has historically been not that great. I actually have just spent the last couple of weeks working on getting the interrupt controller into better shape (which was the major "this is broken" bit), though, which ought to make it into the 2.9 release. May have time to look at some currently-unimplemented features (MPU, Cortex-M4 floating point, etc) after that...